# Disable any :hover, :focus and :active css from being applied

Tags: css

I'm using jQuery Mobile to develop some html5 apps, and its a real pain to manually override every single small thing that gets applied to elements on hover, focus and active.

Is there some way to disable the application of these effect, across the board?

If there only were a way to do something like this in CSS?

```
*:focus, *:hover, *:active {
 return; // this would stop any css effects on these events to be applied
}
```

Comment: If you are already using jquery why don't unbind the hover event for all elements?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible to my knowledge (in CSS).

Comment: I have tried doing this `$('.mybutton').off('hover');` but css is still applied when i hover over the buttons with this class on it.

Comment: There is not a way to quickly do this in CSS. Maybe you could try to search for :hover etc. in the source code for the jquery mobile library and remove it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can "disable" some styles pretty easily but most will just be a ton of cat and mouse for you to make sure there's no styling applied.

You will need to cover specificity cases if something like an anchor tag might have `cursor: pointer` and `text-decoration: underline` as defaults while most other styles will not have this.

Although I recommend against this, if you need to make sure this works will least amount of work you can try adding the `!important` after each property like below:

`*:hover {
  outline: none !important;
}`

In case you're looking for a "clean" slate to start with, you can use [Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), and this will reset most of your styles and help them look nice in case browsers are styling them.